# How can I connect Visual Studio 2019 to SAP HANA?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hana

I am trying to follow this link: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/05/how-to-connect-microsoft-ssis-with-sap-hana/
to connect Visual Studio 2019 to SAP HANA.

I have SAP HANA client installed:
[image]

But when I open Visual Studio 2019 and I want to add a new connection, I can't find it:

[image]

How could I solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Agustín

UPDATE!

I checked that I have the SAP HANA client installed:
[image]

And also the DSN:

[image]

But I still can't see the SAP HANA connector:

[image]

Comment: I don't know that you need to worry about it working in Steps 2 to 4. The important part, from an SSIS perspective will be the 1 time creation of a DSN in step 15 (likely 64 bit to align with your installed driver and not the VS bittedness). You'll then be able to use an ODBC destination as subsequent steps describe

Comment: `I have sap client installed` how do you know that? did you follow the [official tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-clients-install.html)? is the client listed in PATH?

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, thank you for answer me! Yes, I have sap client installed but I can´t see the connector. When I write hdbsql -v in cmd, I see: HDBSQL version 2.14.24.1669924430, the SAP HANA Database interactive terminal.
Copyright 2000-2022 by SAP SE.
How could I solve it?

Comment: No need to add the software editor "sap" because HANA software is sufficient (same as "microsoft" tag is not needed/used in Microsoft software questions). See the tag info: "DO NOT USE THIS TAG as it's ambiguous. Try using one of SAP's product/technology names instead. List of known SAP tags on Stack Overflow can be found here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404098"